# Get html5 data attribute from event inline

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to get the data attribute in this way (my doctype is html5):

```
<a href="#my-link" data-zoom="15" onclick="alert(this.data-zoom); return false;">link</a>
```

but I'm getting error and if use `onclick="alert(this.zoom)` it gets undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the [dataset](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml) property? Then that'll do it:

```
alert(this.dataset.zoom);
```

Comment: BTW: great feature, that `dataset`. I never had heard of it.